# simple-xml preserve comments and ignored elements on deserialization/serialization

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, simple-framework

I'm using [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) framework deserialize an xml into an object, modify it and serialize it again.
The xml I provide is a configuration xml with comments and some unused nodes. I would like to be able to serialize or "update" the xml with the values without making it remove the comments or the unused nodes.

I was able to do it with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) as mentioned here:
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html

But now I'm making an android application and JAXB is not supported so I've switched to simple but I can't seem to find a way to make it.

Can I do it with simple? or somehow using android? without having to manually read DOM and update nodes manually?